# npm install fails in electron app with node: command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am trying to run an electron app on my windows 10 machine.

I have cloned the [electron-quick-start](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#trying-this-example) example, but when I run `npm install` I get the following output:

```
> electron@2.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\aiden\Documents\BVN\GitHub\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

/bin/bash: node: command not found
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! electron@2.0.0 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@2.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-16T05_51_27_649Z-debug.log
```

When I run the following commands I get:

`npm -v`: 
`6.1.0`

`where npm`:
`C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm`
`C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd`

`node -v`: `v10.6.0`
`where node`:
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`

node from the command line runs fine (e.g. `node hello.js`)

I can run `npm install <package>` on some packages with no error, e.g. `npm install node-gyp` but not others: `npm install serialport` or `npm install electron`

My suspicion is that it's not related to Electron, but I've mentioned it for the sake of completeness (in case it's a tangential relationship).

Comment: Electron takes a while to be downloaded. Did you wait enough? (or the download is broken)

Comment: I get a similar output `npm ERR!` output as above. So don't believe it is a download issue.